# jQuery append not working from other Computer

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

I fetch the html from an other website, check for specific text and want to append a paragraph if the specific text is found.

Problem is, that if I run it on my computer and test it on my webserver, output will be appended. If somebody else is trying to use my script from another machine, the script does not append a new paragraph and I don't see why.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <head>


    <style>
        .color{color:red}
      </style>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>


      <h3>Enter Website</h3>
        <input id="input" placeholder="http://example.com" name="input_field">
        <input type="button" id="search" value="SUCHE" onclick="jQuery.get();" />

      <!-- Text will be injected into the id output_gsvo_ready -->
      <h4> Find at website </h4> 
      <div class="a" id="append_cBox"> </div> <br>
      <div id="append_sButton"> </div> <br>
      <div id="append_gAnalytics"> </div> <br>
      <div id="append_gFonts"> </div>
  </body>


  <script>




   jQuery(search).click(function(){
            //Save data from website as mydata
            var mydata = "";
            const website = jQuery("input").val();
            const proxyurl = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";
               //Get and save requested website data 
               jQuery.get(proxyurl + website, function (data) {
                        console.log('data is' + data);
                        mydata = data;

            //Var Program is checking for if existent on website 
            var cookie = document.cookie;
            var shareButton = ('fb-share-button');
            var googleAnalytics = ('function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m)');
            var googleExternalFonts = ('href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/');

            console.log('XXXXXXXXXXXXXX'  + cookie)


             //find content at page and output a paragraph if somethins is found
            // if(cookie.indexOf("wordpress_test_cookie") >= 0) {jQuery('#append_cBox').append('NEIN - Es werden Cookies

abgefragt').attr('class', 'color');};
                if(cookie.indexOf("wordpress_test_cookie") >= 0) {jQuery('#append_cBox').append('<p>NEIN - Es werden Cookies abgefragt</p>').attr('class', 'color');};
                if(mydata.search(shareButton) !== -1) {jQuery('#append_sButton').append('NEIN - Es wurde ein Share button gefunden').attr('class', 'color' );};
                if(mydata.search(googleAnalytics) !== -1) {jQuery('#append_gAnalytics').append('NEIN - Google Analystics gefunden').attr('class', 'color');};
                if(mydata.search(googleExternalFonts) !== -1)  {jQuery('#append_gFonts').append('NEIN - Externe Google-Fonts gefunden').attr('class','color');};           
         });
        });
     </script>
    </html>
```

And this what I looks like if something is found on the website if I try it on my machine:
[image: Working picture of appending jQuery]

Comment: My guess is they are not opening your page on web server and are opening from `file://` protocol where ajax requests are restricted by browsers for security reasons. Can you confirm?

Comment: Hey, I might be wrong, but I hosted my script on my webserver, so I think it should be "http://".
http://richterpatrick.de/website_check.html